# Dealing with null in update where clause without hard-coding a statement

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, null, sql-update

I want to write a method that generates an `update` statement, without hard-coding columns and values. The statement is going to include optional `where` clause and is going to be passed to `executemany`, the clause contains only columns and values, there is no `select` in there. Example:

```
update TABLE
set
    Col1 = 'a',
    Col2 = 'b',
    Col3 = 'c'
where
    Col4 = 'd'
        and Col5 = 'e'
        and Col1 is null;
```

What I wrote so far:

```
def update(self, table_name, update_columns, values, where_columns=None, where=True):
    update_columns_and_values = self.generator.generateColumnsAndPlaceholders(update_columns)
    if where:
        where_clause = self.generator.generateWhereClause(where_columns)
    else:
        where_clause = ''
    query = '''
            update {t}
            set
                {cv}
            {w}
        '''.format(t=table_name, cv=update_columns_and_values, w=where_clause)
    self.cursor.executemany(query, values)
    self.connection.commit()

def generateColumnsAndPlaceholders(columns):
    if type(columns) is str:
        columns = columns.split(', ')
    return ', \n'.join([str(c) + ' = ' + "'%s'" for c in columns])
```

Now, how should I write a function `generateWhereClause` that takes any number of columns and returns a `where` clause with placeholders adjusted for both a not null value (indicated with `=`) and a null value (indicated with `is null`)? 
Also, I think that string returned by `generateColumnsAndPlaceholders` is not prepared for `null` due to single quotes around placeholders. If so, how should I change it?

In general, how do I deal with `null` in update statement without hard-coding specific statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that generates the query - it takes table name, dictionary of values for columns `{column: value}` and dictionary of constraints, that respects None as constraint `{column: constraint}`

```
def update_query(table_name, values, constraints):
    v_list = [k + '=' + '"' + v + '"' for k, v in values.iteritems()]
    v_query = ', '.join(v_list)
    c_list = [k + (' IS NULL' if c is None else '=' + '"' + c + '"') for k, c in constraints.iteritems()]
    c_query = ' AND '.join(c_list)
    return 'UPDATE ' + table_name + ' SET ' + v_query + ' WHERE ' + c_query
```

Test code:

```
tn = "table"
vl = {"Col1":"a","Col2":"b","Col3":"c"}
cn = {"Col4":"d","Col5":"e","Col":None}
```

Result:

```
UPDATE table SET Col2="b", Col3="c", Col1="a" WHERE Col6 IS NULL AND Col4="d" AND Col5="e"
```

I hope order is not an issue for you.